# Qt, get data inside a child widget from another child widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, parent

I create new  cad widget in my mainwindow:

```
glWidget = new MeshViewerWidget(this);
```

and then my text view widget:

```
tbl = new tableView( this );
```

in my mainwindow i can get my mesh with:

```
glWidget->mesh();
```

How do i get it in my tableview.cc? ty

Comment: I use Qt from python using PySide so, I can't give you C++ code, but the princliples are the same. Subclass tableview, with a custom constructor that takes an additional parameter, so you can pass in the mesh when you instantiate the tableview. Alternatively, add a setMesh method to tableview subclass and pass in the mesh that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#findChildren) function of `QObject` and get a list of all children of a widget that can be casted to the given type. Eg

```
QList<QTableView*> allTableViews = glWidget->findChildren<QTableView *>();
// Iterate in order to find the table view either by checking the name, the parent etc....
```

Another approach would be the one Simon suggests, subclassing and adding public access function to the members you want to be reachable from top level widgets.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: glWidget->findChildren will give me list od all children of glWidget? I am confused, coz I would need children of my MainWindow() if i want to get glWidget listed among them. But why, I already know the name (glWidget)? As I see it the child can't see he's "brother" data? Just with help of the parent with a custom constructor? Big n00b here...

Comment: I got it like this:

 QList<MeshViewerWidget*> allmeshwidgets = parentWidget()->findChildren<MeshViewerWidget *>();
 MyMesh &mesh = allmeshwidgets.first()->mesh();

Thanks for all the help!